# Are there subsets of every size in a union-closed family?

Tags: combinatorics, examples-counterexamples

Let $X$ be a finite set with at least one element and $\eta\subseteq\mathcal{P}(X)$ a union-closed collection of subsets of $X$ such that
$$X=\bigcup_{A\in\eta}A$$
$$\forall x,y\in X\text{ there exists }A\in\eta\text{ such that }A\text{ contains one of them but not the other}$$
$$\emptyset\notin\eta$$
and let $q=\min_{A\in\eta}|A|$

Is it true that for every $q\le k\le|X|$ there exists $A\in\eta$ such that $|A|=k$ ? It is obviously true for $k=q$ and $k=|X|$, and I also [know](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4183909/how-many-sets-are-there-in-a-union-closed-family-over-a-set-of-given-size/4185249#4185249) it to be true for $k=|X|-1$. I'm trying to use a similar argument with
$$k_{min}=\min\{\,k\;:\;\nexists A\in\eta\;\;\text{with}\;\;|A|=k\,\}$$
$$k_{max}=\max\{\,k\;:\;\nexists A\in\eta\;\;\text{with}\;\;|A|=k\,\}$$
because then for every $q\le k<k_{min}$ and $k_{max}<k\le|X|$ there exists an $A\in\eta$ with $|A|=k$ and then contradicting the minimality/maximality, but the proof seems elusive.
There might be a nice, simple counterexample but I can't find it.

If it were false, I would like to know how you came up with a counterexample and if a weaker result, like $k_{min}=k_{max}$ or $k_{max}-k_{min}\le q$, could be possible.

Thanks!

Comment: You seem to be assuming $X$ is finite, is that right?

Comment: @FarmerS yes, $X$ is finite

Comment: If I'm interpreting the conditions correctly, then the simple family $\{1\}$, $\{1,2,3\}$, $\{1,2,4\}$, $\{1,2,3,4\}$ is a counterexample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A convoluted counterexample: Let $n$ be some large even integer, say $n\geq 100$. Let $A = 2^{[n]} \setminus \{\emptyset\}$. Let $X$ be the set
$$   X = \{ x_1,\ldots, x_n, y_1,\ldots, y_n \} .$$
Let $\eta$ be the following set of subsets of $X$: For any $B\in A$, let
$$  \{ y_i \mid i\in B \} \cup \{x_i \mid i\in B\}   $$
be included in $\eta$. Also, for all $z\in X$, let $X\setminus \{z\}$ be included in $\eta$. Let no other sets be included in $\eta$. The inclusion of the sets $X\setminus \{z\}$ means that any two elements are separated by a set in $\eta$. Also, the union of any two sets in $\eta$ is again in $\eta$. Moreover, $\eta$ contains sets of size $2,4,\ldots, 2n-2, 2n-1,2n$. Notice that the only set of odd size that $\eta$ contains are the sets $X\setminus \{z\}$ of size $2n-1$. The family $\eta$ does not contains sets of size $3,5,...2n-3$.

Comment: Wow really nice counterexample!

Comment: The sets $X\setminus\{z\}$ have size $2n-1$

Comment: @augustoperez Ah yes, let me correct that mistake!